How to implement VXLAN/GRETAP tunnel on Juniper MX routers?
Implementing VXLAN is widely documented for Juniper MX routers on connecting two networks. However, I find it's rather difficult to find a equivalent implement of the following Linux command:
ip link add tun9 type vxlan/gretap local <src IP> remote <dst IP> dstport 4789 id <vid> ttl 255
ip link set tun9 up
ip addr add <local IP>/22 dev tun9
ip addr add <local IP>/64 dev tun9

Anyone can share some thoughts on how to implement it in Juniper MX?
With the example:
(remote host 192.168.1.1/24) 1.1.1.1 ---- GRETAP --- 9.9.9.9 (Juniper MX 192.168.1.2/24)

I tried the following configs:
interfaces {
  gr-1/0/0 {
    unit 0 {
      tunnel {
        source 9.9.9.9;
        destination 1.1.1.1;
      }
      family bridge {
        interface-mode access;
        vlan-id 100;
      }
    }
  }
  lt-1/0/0 {
    unit 1 {
      encapsulation ethernet-bridge;
      peer-unit 2;
      family bridge {
        interface-mode access;
        vlan-id 100;
      }
    }
    unit 2 {
      encapsulation ethernet;
      peer-unit 1;
      family inet {
        address 192.168.1.2/24;
      }
    }
  }
}

routing-instances {
  mygretap {
    instance-type virtual-switch;
    bridge-domain {
      bd0 {
        vlan-id 100;
      }
    }
    interface gr-1/0/0.0;
    interface lt-1/0/0.1;
  }
  myrouter {
    instance-type virtual-router;
    interface gr-1/0/0.0;
    interface lt-1/0/0.2;
  }
}

When I ping the remote host:
ping 192.168.1.1 routing-instance myrouter source 192.168.1.2

all requests timed out.
I ran
tcpdump -vvvv -i lt-1/0/0.2

and find there are ARP requests here. However, I ran
tcpdump -vvvv -i lt-1/0/0.1

and I find there are no traffic at all.
Where is the problem and how shall I fix the configuration?

Exactly where is your problem when adapting those essential steps to MX?

@Zac67 I added some links, which I have issue understanding how to adapt them. For L3 GRE, it's easy since all I need is to translate the Linux command to interface/gr-0/0/0/unit 0/tunnel. But for VXLAN or GRETAP, I can't understand how to adapt the process.
